# What's the algorithm behind sleep()?

Tags: c, algorithm, language-agnostic, sleep

Now there's something I always wondered: how is sleep() implemented ?

If it is all about using an API from the OS, then how is the API made ?

Does it all boil down to using special machine-code on the CPU ? Does that CPU need a special co-processor or other gizmo without which you can't have sleep() ?

The best known incarnation of sleep() is in C (to be more accurate, in the libraries that come with C compilers, such as GNU's libc), although almost every language today has its equivalent, but the implementation of sleep in some languages (think Bash) is not what we're looking at in this question...

EDIT: After reading some of the answers, I see that the process is placed in a wait queue. From there, I can guess two alternatives, either

1. a timer is set so that the kernel wakes the process at the due time, or
2. whenever the kernel is allowed a time slice, it polls the clock to check whether it's time to wake a process.

The answers only mention alternative 1. Therefore, I ask: how does this timer behave ? If it's a simple interrupt to make the kernel wake the process, how can the kernel ask the timer to "wake me up in 140 milliseconds so I can put the process in running state" ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The "update" to question shows some misunderstanding of how modern OSs work.

The kernel is not "allowed" a time slice. The kernel is the thing that gives out time slices to user processes. The "timer" is not set to wake the sleeping process up - it is set to stop the currently running process.

In essence, the kernel attempts to fairly distribute the CPU time by stopping processes that are on CPU too long. For a simplified picture, let's say that no process is allowed to use the CPU more than 2 milliseconds. So, the kernel would set timer to 2 milliseconds, and let the process run. When the timer fires an interrupt, the kernel gets control. It saves the running process' current state (registers, instruction pointer and so on), and the control is not returned to it. Instead, another process is picked from the list of processes waiting to be given CPU, and the process that was interrupted goes to the back of the queue.

The sleeping process is simply *not* in the queue of things waiting for CPU. Instead, it's stored in the sleeping queue. Whenever kernel gets timer interrupt, the sleep queue is checked, and the processes whose time have come get transferred to "waiting for CPU" queue.

This is, of course, a gross simplification. It takes very sophisticated algorithms to ensure security, fairness, balance, prioritize, prevent starvation, do it all fast and with minimum amount of memory used for kernel data.

Comment: IIRC, 10ms is a typical timeslice for Linux processes.  Linux can pre-empt processes in the middle of their 10ms timeslice to achieve much better timer accuracy than that.  (Before Linux implemented pre-emption, some people compiled their kernel with `HZ=1000` instead of `HZ=100`, to get 1ms jiffies.  See for example, http://serverfault.com/questions/377947/1000-hz-linux-kernel-necessary-if-i-have-tickless-and-high-resolution-timer.  Multi-core CPUs have made this much less important, too, since the locking needed for SMP makes supporting pre-emption much cheaper. And there's often a free core

Comment: this is a good response but the reader should also understand that just because you're in the sleeping queue, you're not bound by the time you asked for.  For example, if you have subscribed to a signal and the signal is comes while in the sleep queue, the process can regain CPU time sooner.  I/O wait events (select...) have similar effect.  See EINTR errno which Linux sleep can return.

Answer (score 36):

There's a kernel data structure called the sleep queue.  It's a priority queue.  Whenever a process is added to the sleep queue, the expiration time of the most-soon-to-be-awakened process is calculated, and a timer is set.  At that time, the expired job is taken off the queue and the process resumes execution.

(amusing trivia:  in older unix implementations, there was a queue for processes for which fork() had been called, but for which the child process had not been created.  It was of course called the ***fork queue***.)

HTH!

Comment: There's a kernel data structure called the sleep queue in what kernel(s)?

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps the major job of an operating system is to hide the complexity of a real piece of hardware from the application writer.  Hence, any description of how the OS works runs the risk of getting really complicated, really fast.  Accordingly, I am not going to deal with all the "what ifs" and yeah buts" that a real operating system needs to deal with.  I'm just going to describe, at a high conceptual level, what a process is, what the scheduler does, how the timer queue works.  Hopefully this is helpful.

**What's a process:**

Think of a process--let's just talk about processes, and get to threads later--as "the thing the operating system schedules".  A process has an ID--think an integer--and you can think of that integer as an index into a table containing all the context of that process.

*Context* is the hardware information--registers, memory management unit contents, other hardware state--that, when loaded into the machine, will allow the process to "go".  There are other components of context--lists of open files, state of signal handlers, and, most importantly here, *things the process is waiting for*.

**Processes spend a lot of time sleeping (a.k.a. waiting)**

A process spends much of its time waiting.  For example, a process that reads or writes to disk will spend a lot of time waiting for the data to arrive or be acknowledged to be out on disk.  OS folks use the terms "waiting" and "sleeping" (and "blocked") somewhat interchangeably--all meaning that the process is awaiting something to happen before it can continue on its merry way.  It is just confusing that the OS API sleep() happens to use underlying OS mechanisms for sleeping processes.

Processes can be waiting for other things:  network packets to arrive, window selection events, or a timer to expire, for example.

**Processes and Scheduling**

Processes that are waiting are said to be *non-runnable*.  They don't go onto the run queue of the operating system.  But when the event occurs which the process is waiting for, it causes the operating system to move the process from the non-runnable to the runnable state.  At the same time, the operating system puts the process on the run queue, which is really not a queue--it's more of a pile of all the processes which, should the operating system decide to do so, *could* run.

**Scheduling:**

the operating system decides, at regular intervals, which processes should run.  The algorithm by which the operating system decides to do so is called, somewhat unsurprisingly, the scheduling algorithm.  Scheduling algorithms range from dead-simple ("everybody gets to run for 10 ms, and then the next guy on the queue gets to run") to far more complicated (taking into account process priority, frequency of execution, run-time deadlines, inter-process dependencies, chained locks and all sorts of other complicated subject matter).

**The Timer Queue**
A computer has a timer inside it.  There are many ways this can be implemented, but the classic manner is called a *periodic timer*.  A periodic timer ticks at a regular interval--in most operating systems today, I believe this rate is 100 times per second--100 Hz--every 10 milliseconds.  I'll use that value in what follows as a concrete rate, but know that most operating systems worth their salt can be configured with different ticks--and many don't use this mechanism and can provide much better timer precision.  But I digress.

Each tick results in an interrupt to the operating system.

When the OS handles this timer interrupt, it increments its idea of system time by another 10 ms.  Then, it looks at the timer queue and decides what events on that queue need to be dealt with.

The timer queue really *is* a queue of "things which need to be dealt with", which we will call events.  This queue is ordered by time of expiration, soonest events first.

An "event" can be something like, "wake up process X", or "go kick disk I/O over there, because it may have gotten stuck", or "send out a keepalive packet on that fibrechannel link over there".  Whatever the operating system needs to have done.

When you have a queue ordered in this way, it's easy to manage the dequeuing.  The OS simply looks at the head of the queue, and decrements the "time to expiration" of the event by 10 ms every tick.  When the expiration time goes to zero, the OS dequeues that event, and does whatever is called for.

In the case of a sleeping process, it simply makes the process runnable again.

Simple, huh?

Answer (score 10):

there's at least two different levels to answer this question.  (and a lot of other things that get confused with it, i won't touch them)

1. an application level, this is what the C library does.  It's a simple OS call, it simply tells the OS not to give CPU time to this process until the time has passed.  The OS has a queue of suspended applications, and some info about what are they waiting for (usually either time, or some data to appear somewhere).
2. kernel level. when the OS doesn't have anything to do right now, it executes a 'hlt' instruction.  this instruction doesn't do anything, but it never finishes by itself.  Of course, a hardware interrupt is serviced normally.  Put simply, the main loop of an OS looks like this (from very very far away):

   ```
   allow_interrupts ();
   while (true) {
     hlt;
     check_todo_queues ();
   }
   ```

   the interrupt handlers simpy add things to the todo queues.  The real time clock is programmed to generate interrupts either periodically (at a fixed rate), or to some fixed time in the future when the next process wants to be awaken.

Comment: Nicely put. Application level explained at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33639161/895245

Answer (score 9):

A multitasking operating system has a component called a scheduler, this component is responsible for giving CPU time to threads, calling sleep tells the OS not to give CPU time to this thread for some time.

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_states for complete details.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know anything about Linux, but I can tell you what happens on Windows.

Sleep() causes the process' time-slice to end immediately to return control to the OS. The OS then sets up a timer kernel object that gets signaled after the time elapses. The OS will then not give that process any more time until the kernel object gets signaled. Even then, if other processes have higher or equal priority, it may still wait a little while before letting the process continue.

Special CPU machine code is used by the OS to do process switching. Those functions cannot be accessed by user-mode code, so they are accessed strictly by API calls into the OS.

Answer (score 5):

Essentially, yes, there is a "special gizmo" - and it's important for a lot more than just sleep().

Classically, on x86 this was an Intel 8253 or 8254 "Programmable Interval Timer".  In the early PCs, this was a seperate chip on the motherboard that could be programmed by the CPU to assert an interrupt (via the "Programmable Interrupt Controller", another discrete chip) after a preset time interval.  The functionality still exists, although it is now a tiny part of a much larger chunk of motherboard circuitry.

The OS today still programs the PIT to wake it up regularly (in recent versions of Linux, once every millisecond by default), and this is how the Kernel is able to implement pre-emptive multitasking.

Answer (score 3):

**glibc 2.21 Linux**

Forwards to the `nanosleep` system call.

glibc is the default implementation for the C stdlib on most Linux desktop distros.

How to find it: the first reflex is:

```
git ls-files | grep sleep
```

This contains:

```
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sleep.c
```

and we know that:

```
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/
```

contains the Linux specifics.

On the top of that file we see:

```
/* We are going to use the `nanosleep' syscall of the kernel.  But the
   kernel does not implement the stupid SysV SIGCHLD vs. SIG_IGN
   behaviour for this syscall.  Therefore we have to emulate it here.  */
unsigned int
__sleep (unsigned int seconds)
```

So if you trust comments, we are done basically.

At the bottom:

```
 weak_alias (__sleep, sleep)
```

which basically says `__sleep` == `sleep`. The function uses `nanosleep` through:

```
result = __nanosleep (&ts, &ts);
```

After greppingg:

```
git grep nanosleep | grep -v abilist
```

we get a small list of interesting occurrences, and I think `__nanosleep` is defined in:

```
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/syscalls.list
```

on the line:

```
nanosleep   -   nanosleep   Ci:pp   __nanosleep nanosleep
```

which is some super DRY magic format parsed by:

```
sysdeps/unix/make-syscalls.sh
```

Then from the build directory:

```
grep -r __nanosleep
```

Leads us to: `/sysd-syscalls` which is what `make-syscalls.sh` generates and contains:

```
#### CALL=nanosleep NUMBER=35 ARGS=i:pp SOURCE=-
ifeq (,$(filter nanosleep,$(unix-syscalls)))
unix-syscalls += nanosleep
$(foreach p,$(sysd-rules-targets),$(foreach o,$(object-suffixes),$(objpfx)$(patsubst %,$p,nanosleep)$o)): \
        $(..)sysdeps/unix/make-syscalls.sh
    $(make-target-directory)
    (echo '#define SYSCALL_NAME nanosleep'; \
     echo '#define SYSCALL_NARGS 2'; \
     echo '#define SYSCALL_SYMBOL __nanosleep'; \
     echo '#define SYSCALL_CANCELLABLE 1'; \
     echo '#include <syscall-template.S>'; \
     echo 'weak_alias (__nanosleep, nanosleep)'; \
     echo 'libc_hidden_weak (nanosleep)'; \
    ) | $(compile-syscall) $(foreach p,$(patsubst %nanosleep,%,$(basename $(@F))),$($(p)CPPFLAGS))
endif
```

It looks like part of a Makefile. `git grep sysd-syscalls` shows that it is included at:

```
sysdeps/unix/Makefile:23:-include $(common-objpfx)sysd-syscalls
```

`compile-syscall` looks like the key part, so we find:

```
# This is the end of the pipeline for compiling the syscall stubs.
# The stdin is assembler with cpp using sysdep.h macros.
compile-syscall = $(COMPILE.S) -o $@ -x assembler-with-cpp - \
                   $(compile-mkdep-flags)
```

Note that `-x assembler-with-cpp` is a `gcc` option.

This `#define`s parameters like:

```
#define SYSCALL_NAME nanosleep
```

and then use them at:

```
#include <syscall-template.S>
```

OK, this is as far as I will go on the macro expansion game for now.

I think then this generates the `posix/nanosleep.o` file which must be linked together with everything.

**Linux 4.2 x86_64 nanosleep syscall**

Uses the scheduler: it's not a busy sleep.

Search ctags:

```
sys_nanosleep
```

Leads us to `kernel/time/hrtimer.c`:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE2(nanosleep, struct timespec __user *, rqtp,
```

`hrtimer` stands for High Resolution Timer. From there the main line looks like:

- `hrtimer_nanosleep`
- `do_nanosleep`

  - `set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);` which is interruptible sleep
  - `freezable_schedule();` which calls `schedule()` and allows other processes to run
- `hrtimer_start_expires`
- `hrtimer_start_range_ns`
- TODO: reach the `arch/x86` timing level
- TODO: are the above steps done directly in the syscal call interrupt handler, or in a regular kernel thread?

A few articles about it:

- https://geeki.wordpress.com/2010/10/30/ways-of-sleeping-in-linux-kernel/
- http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8144

Comment: I wouldn't spend so much of the answer talking about how `sleep(3)` is implemented on top of `nanosleep(2)` by glibc.  That's not the interesting part, IMO.  I'd maybe spend one sentence on that at the top, then maybe get back to a glibc source file location at the bottom of the answer.  BTW, single-stepping in a debugger, or using `strace` to trace system calls for a test program, would have been an easier way to find out that glibc's `sleep` uses `nanosleep`.  It wouldn't save you the trouble of wading through the source if you want to see the actual translation layer source code, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes you are right! Just getting ready to some day hack glibc and satisfying my curiosity.