# How to pause for a non-integer amount of time in C?

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing a simple program, and it gives me an error when I pass a non-integer value to the sleep() function. Is there another function, or a different way to use sleep(), that will allow me to pause the program temporarily for less than a second (or, say, 2.5)?

> mario.c:34:13: error: implicit declaration of function 'usleep' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>                usleep(30000);
>                ^

Comment: Are you Linux? Windows? Something else?

Comment: Did you try http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep ?

Comment: I think most of them will let you use ms (milliseconds) .

Comment: Use usleep as described in http://stackoverflow.com/q/1157209/1174052

Comment: I'm on Linux, I tried usleep but it gave me an error. I included unistd.h.

Comment: if you have access to C11 there is [`thrd_sleep`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_sleep)

Comment: what options are you passing to gcc? you may be enabling pedantic mode for standards compliance. depending on what you are targeting, you may want a combination of 'sleep' and 'usleep' or 'nanosleep'

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This will let you specify a delay as a float in seconds.
The function executes until the difference between start and stop is greater than the requested delay.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void floatdelay ( float delay);

int main()
{
    float pause = 1.2;
    floatdelay ( pause);
    return 0;
}

void floatdelay ( float delay)
{
    clock_t start;
    clock_t stop;

    start = clock();
    stop = clock();
    while ( ( (float)( stop - start)/ CLOCKS_PER_SEC) < delay) {
        stop = clock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not ideal, but since the other solutions don't seem to work for me (both usleep and nanosleep cause errors), this is the best one.

Comment: The solution spins, eating up the CPU time.

Comment: Seems to be the only one that works with my system, not changing my settings. Good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 4):

[`usleep`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep) will pause for a particular number of microseconds. For example:

```
usleep(500000);
```

will pause for half a second.

On some systems, and depending on compiler configuration etc, you may need to define `_GNU_SOURCE` before including `unistd.h` (ideally, at the start of the source file), with:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

Comment: Although if you are on Windows, there is no `usleep().`  There, you would use `Sleep(n)` with milliseconds as the parameter n.

Comment: When I use usleep it gives me an error, I updated question with the given error.

Comment: Both `usleep` and `nanosleep` are "newer" features which require turning on extensions over the original/antique interfaces.

Comment: @NoahTronic what is your Linux distribution, gcc version and glibc version? (For the last one, run `/lib/libc.so.6`. For the second one, `gcc --version`)

Comment: Actually, `_GNU_SOURCE` should be defined in the build-system rather than within a source-file, due to the way predefined symbols are handled.  As I noted below, those functions have been available for quite a while.

Answer (score 2):

POSIX.1-2001 standard defines function [`nanosleep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html), which is perfect for this. Unlike `sleep()` and `usleep()`, `nanosleep()` does not interfere with signals.

Current Linux C libraries tend to implement `usleep()` as a wrapper around `nanosleep()`, however. You can see this if you `strace` a test program (say, run `strace /bin/sleep 1`).

However, as `nanosleep()` is part of POSIX.1-2001 standard, it is definitely recommended.

For example:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* Sleep; returns un-slept (leftover) time.
*/
double dsleep(const double seconds)
{
    const long  sec = (long)seconds;
    const long  nsec = (long)((seconds - (double)sec) * 1e9);
    struct timespec  req, rem;

    if (sec < 0L)
        return 0.0;
    if (sec == 0L && nsec <= 0L)
        return 0.0;

    req.tv_sec = sec;
    if (nsec <= 0L)
        req.tv_nsec = 0L;
    else
    if (nsec <= 999999999L)
        req.tv_nsec = nsec;
    else
        req.tv_nsec = 999999999L;

    rem.tv_sec = 0;
    rem.tv_nsec = 0;

    if (nanosleep(&req, &rem) == -1) {
        if (errno == EINTR)
            return (double)rem.tv_sec + (double)rem.tv_nsec / 1000000000.0;
        else
            return seconds;
    } else
        return 0.0;
}
```

Most of the logic above is to make sure (regardless of floating-point rounding mode et cetera) that the nanoseconds field is always within [0, 999999999], inclusive, and to make it safe to call it with negative values (in which case it'll just return zero).

If you want to specify the duration in integer milliseconds, you could use

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* Sleep; returns un-slept (leftover) time.
*/
long msleep(const long ms)
{
    struct timespec  req, rem;

    if (ms <= 0L)
        return 0L;

    req.tv_sec = ms / 1000L;
    req.tv_nsec = (ms % 1000L) * 1000000L;
    rem.tv_sec = 0;
    rem.tv_nsec = 0;

    if (nanosleep(&req, &rem) == -1) {
        if (errno == EINTR)
            return (long)rem.tv_sec * 1000L + rem.tv_nsec / 1000000L;
        else
            return ms;
    } else
        return 0L;
}
```

It is not necessary to zero out `rem`, above, but written this way, these two functions are extremely robust, even against an occasional system hiccup or library bug.

Answer (score 0):

The apparent problem with the original suggestion to use `usleep` was overlooking `_GNU_SOURCE`, a given for Linux with almost any POSIX-extension.

This compiles without warning for me, using `c99` with the strict warning flags:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{             
    usleep(1);
    nanosleep(0,0);
    return 0;
}
```

and (extracted from other scripts)

```
ACTUAL_GCC=c99 gcc-stricter -D_GNU_SOURCE -c foo.c

#!/bin/sh
OPTS="-O -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshadow -Wconversion 
-W 
    -Wbad-function-cast 
    -Wcast-align 
    -Wcast-qual 
    -Wmissing-declarations 
    -Wnested-externs 
    -Wpointer-arith 
    -Wwrite-strings 
    -ansi 
    -pedantic 
 "
${ACTUAL_GCC:-gcc} $OPTS "$@"
```

The `usleep` and `nanosleep` functions are *extensions*, as noted.  More commonly, [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/select) or [`poll`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/poll) are used.  Those functions are used to wait for a specified interval of time for activity on one or more open files. As a special case, `select` does not even have to wait for a file, but simply use the time interval.  Like `nanosleep`, `select` uses a structure for the time interval to allow double-precision values -- but its range of values starts with microseconds while `nanosleep` starts with nanoseconds.

These functions are all part of the Linux C library.

ncurses (like any X/Open curses) provides a function [`napms`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_kernel.3x.html) which waits for milliseconds.  Internally, ncurses uses (since [1998](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t980207)) `nanosleep` or `usleep` depending on their availability (they are extensions after all), or an internal function that uses `select` or `poll`, also depending on availability.

Answer (score 0):

Use this macro to pause for non-integer seconds:

```
#include "unistd.h"
#define mysleep(s) usleep(s*1000000)
```

Answer (score -1):

sleep()'s int value is for a pause time in milliseconds, not seconds.  So, to pause for one second, you'd pass it 1000. For 2.5 seconds, you'd pass it 2500.  For a half second, you'd pass 500.

Comment: perhaps you were thinking of `usleep()` -- if on UNIX -- which take microseconds (not milliseconds)

Comment: `sleep()` is not a C standard function.  The time units for `sleep()` vary.  Stating your compiler/OS helps.