# Wake up a std::thread from usleep

Tags: c++, multithreading

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <signal.h>
#include <thread>

void sleepy() {
    usleep(1.0E15);
}

int main() {
    std :: thread sleepy_thread(sleepy);

    // Wake it up somehow...?

    sleepy_thread.join();
}
```

Here we have a thread that just sleeps forever. I want to join it, without having to wait forever for it to spontaneously wake from usleep. Is there a way to tell it from the extern "hey man, wake up!", so that I can join it in a reasonable amount of time?

I am definitely not an expert on threads, so if possible don't assume anything.

Comment: IIRC `usleep(1.0E15);` doesn't take a `float` or `double` value??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: So what? `1e15` is implicitly convertible to `int`. Though that's a pretty bit `int`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit _"Though that's a pretty bit `int`"_ was my point of course. Anyways leaves that being a big value.

Comment: @OP Also you should note, that `usleep()` is [actually deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157209/is-there-an-alternative-sleep-function-in-c-to-milliseconds).

Comment: How about sending it a signal?

Answer (score 14):

No, it is not possible using the threads from the standard library.

One possible workaround is to use `condition_variable::sleep_for` along with a `mutex` and a boolean condition.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex mymutex;
std::condition_variable mycond;
bool flag = false;

void sleepy() {
     std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mymutex);
     mycond.wait_for( lock,
                      std::chrono::seconds(1000),
                      []() { return flag; } );
}

int main()
{
    std :: thread sleepy_thread(sleepy);

    {
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mymutex);
       flag = true;
       mycond.notify_one();
    }

    sleepy_thread.join();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/thread.html) library, which implements the *interruption-point* concept:

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

void sleepy()
{
    // this_thread::sleep_for is an interruption point.
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for( boost::chrono::seconds(1000) );
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread t( sleepy );

    t.interrupt();
    t.join();

}
```

Comment: Why do we need the mutex in the first example? Can't we use instead an atomic bool?

Comment: @Alex See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). In particular "Even if the shared variable is atomic, it must be modified while owning the mutex to correctly publish the modification to the waiting thread."

Answer (score 6):

Other answers are saying you can use a timed muted to accomplish this. I've put together a small class using a timed mutex to block the 'sleeping' threads, and release the mutex if you want to 'wake' them early. The standard library provides a function for `timed_mutex` called `try_lock_for` which will try to lock a mutex for a period of time, before continuing on anyway (and returning an indication of failure)

This can be encapsulated in a class, like the following implementation, which only allows a single call to wake waiting threads. It could also be improved by including a `waitUntil` function for waiting until a time series to correspond to the `timed_mutex`'s other timed waiting function, `try_lock_until` but I will leave that as an exercise to the interested, since it seems a simple modification.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>

// one use wakable sleeping class
class InterruptableSleeper{
    std::timed_mutex
        mut_;
    std::atomic_bool
        locked_; // track whether the mutex is locked
    void lock(){ // lock mutex
        mut_.lock();
        locked_ = true;
    }
    void unlock(){ // unlock mutex
        locked_ = false;
        mut_.unlock();
    }
public:
    // lock on creation
    InterruptableSleeper() {
        lock();
    }
    // unlock on destruction, if wake was never called
    ~InterruptableSleeper(){
        if(locked_){
            unlock();
        }
    }
    // called by any thread except the creator
    // waits until wake is called or the specified time passes
    template< class Rep, class Period >
    void sleepFor(const std::chrono::duration<Rep,Period>& timeout_duration){
        if(mut_.try_lock_for(timeout_duration)){
            // if successfully locked, 
            // remove the lock
            mut_.unlock();
        }
    }
    // unblock any waiting threads, handling a situation
    // where wake has already been called.
    // should only be called by the creating thread
    void wake(){
        if(locked_){
            unlock();
        }
    }
};
```

---

The following code:

```
void printTimeWaited(
  InterruptableSleeper& sleeper, 
  const std::chrono::milliseconds& duration){
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Started sleep...";
    sleeper.sleepFor(duration);
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout 
        << "Ended sleep after "
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count()
        << "ms.\n";
}

void compareTimes(unsigned int sleep, unsigned int waker){
    std::cout << "Begin test: sleep for " << sleep << "ms, wakeup at " << waker << "ms\n";
    InterruptableSleeper
        sleeper;
    std::thread
        sleepy(&printTimeWaited, std::ref(sleeper), std::chrono::milliseconds{sleep});
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{waker});
    sleeper.wake();
    sleepy.join();
    std::cout << "End test\n";
}

int main(){

    compareTimes(1000, 50);
    compareTimes(50, 1000);

}
```

prints

```
Begin test: sleep for 1000ms, wakeup at 50ms
Started sleep...Ended sleep after 50ms.
End test
Begin test: sleep for 50ms, wakeup at 1000ms
Started sleep...Ended sleep after 50ms.
End test
```

Example & Use on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98fdcd78c99e948c)

Answer (score 2):

> *"Is there a way to tell it from the extern "hey man, wake up!", so that I can join it in a reasonable amount of time?"*

No, there's no way to do so according c++ standard mechanisms.

Well, to get your thread being woken, you'll need a mechanism that leaves other threads in control of it. Besides [`usleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/usleep.html) is a deprecated POSIX function:

> #### Issue 6
>
> The DESCRIPTION is updated to avoid use of the term "must" for application requirements.
>
> **This function is marked obsolescent.**
>
> IEEE Std 1003.1-2001/Cor 2-2004, item XSH/TC2/D6/144 is applied, updating the DESCRIPTION from "process' signal mask" to "thread's signal mask", and adding a statement that the `usleep()` function need not be reentrant.

there's no way you could get control of another thread, that's going to call that function.
Same thing for any other *`sleep()`* functions even if declared from [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for).

As mentioned in other answers or comments, you'll need to use a timeable synchronization mechanism like a [`std::timed_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/timed_mutex) or a [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) from your thread function.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a semaphore, call [sem_timedwait](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_timedwait) instead of `usleep`, and call [sem_post](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_post) before calling `join`

Comment: My answer using pthread was voted down. This also uses a pthread library.

Comment: Is semaphore actually c++ standard?? The best surrogate I can think of is [`std::condition_variable `](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

Comment: I actually like this idea a lot...! Why was this downvoted?

Comment: The example uses Linux-specific `usleep`, why can't we use Linux-specific semaphores here?

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:(There are many ways to accomplish..also its not good idea to use sleep in your thread)

```
///Define a mutex
void sleepy()
{
    //try to take mutex lock which this thread will get if main thread leaves that
    //usleep(1.0E15);
}


int main()
{
    //Init the Mutex
    //take mutex lock
    std :: thread sleepy_thread(sleepy);

    //Do your work
    //unlock the mutex...This will enable the sleepy thread to run
    sleepy_thread.join();
}
```

Comment: _"its not good ides to use sleep in your thread"_ Why's that then?

Comment: You should flesh out the `std::mutex` parts of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sleep for a short amount of time and look to see if a variable has changed.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>

std::atomic<int> sharedVar(1);
void sleepy()
{
    while (sharedVar.load())
    {
        usleep(500);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std :: thread sleepy_thread(sleepy);
    // wake up
    sharedVar.store(0);
}
```

Comment: This code is illegal because the two accesses to `sharedVar` conflict, according to the C++ standard.

Comment: Can't possibly be illegal. Do you mean Undefined behavior? If sleepy reads an old version of sharedVar in one loop, it will just read the newer value one loop later.

Comment: The issue is not that sleepy might read an old version. The issue is that *anything* can happen.

Comment: At least `std::atomic<int> sharedVar = 1;` please!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Best not, since that doesn't compile.