# Wake thread and exit from sleep

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a singleton class which looks something like:

```
//Test.h
class Test
{
private:
    static std::mutex mtx;
    static std::condition_variable cv;
    static bool end;

    static void DoSomethingThread();
    static void SomeOtherFunction();
public:
    static void Start();
}

//Test.cpp
std::mutex Test::mtx;
std::condition_variable Test::cv;
bool Test::end = false;

void Test::Start() 
{
    std::thread t_thread(Test::DoSomethingThread);

    while(a) {
        if (b) {
            // End thread.
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            Test::end = true;
            Test::cv.notify_one();
            t_thread.join();

            Test::SomeOtherFunction();

            // Restart thread.
            Test::end = false;
            t_thread = std::thread(Test::DoSomethingThread);
        }

        ...
    }
}

void Test::DoSomethingThread()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

    while (1) {
        //Do some work here.

        Test::cv.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(1000), []() { return Test::end; });

        if (Test::end) { break; }
    }
}
```

I found this code on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233019/wake-up-a-stdthread-from-usleep) and to be honest dont really know how this works. But the guy had the same problem as me and I thought it would work for my case to, but it didnt.

So what I currently have is have a thread `t_thread` which runs forever, it does some work and then sleeps for 1000 seconds and all over again. What I need is some way to wake this thread up from sleep and exit it. So `SomeOtherFunction()` can do its work and then restart the thread.

Why doesnt this code works, and how can I make it work?

Comment: Remove answer from question and add as an answer.

Comment: @SteveM Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I went back to original post and did:

```
if (b) {
    {       
        // End thread.
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        Test::end = true;
        Test::cv.notify_one();
    }   

    t_thread.join();

    Test::SomeOtherFunction();

    // Restart thread.
    Test::end = false;
    t_thread = std::thread(Test::DoSomethingThread);
}
```

And it works now. Thanks anyway.