# sleep() with float as parameter not working

Tags: c, floating-point, sleep

I created simple code to test the sleep() function. in C.

I execute the following code in attempts that the program waits 5 seconds before terminating:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n=0;
    for (n=1;n<=10;n++){
        sleep(.5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It however waits about say 100ms. Well, definitely less than one second.

Now if I instead executed the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n=0;
    for (n=1;n<=10;n++){
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program behaves as expected (waits 10 seconds before exiting).

Why does sleep() fail to execute properly when the parameter is a float?

and what's the absolute best function that's compatible with all systems that I can use in place of sleep?

Comment: I'm surprised that a 1k user shows so little research. A quick look at the documentation would have shown you that `sleep` takes an integer as argument. It's also very easy to find the answer to your second question here on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an alternative sleep function in C to milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157209/is-there-an-alternative-sleep-function-in-c-to-milliseconds)

Comment: Also, please read tag descriptions. The debugging tag is completely unsuitable for this question.

Comment: Did you not get a warning about an implicit declaration of `sleep`?

Comment: Please don't think that http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ , but it could be a reason for the downvotes.

Answer (score 11):

Type `man 3 sleep` and read it.

`sleep` requires an `unsigned int` argument. It can only sleep for a whole number of seconds.

If you pass it an argument of a different numeric type, it's implicitly converted to `unsigned int`. Converting a floating-point value to an integer type truncates.

That's assuming that the declaration for the `sleep` function is visible. In your program, you don't have the required `#include <unistd.h>`. In C99 or later, calling a function with no visible declaration is illegal. In C90, the compiler will make certain assumptions about the function. In this case, your program's behavior is undefined.

So `sleep(.5)` is equivalent to `sleep(0)`.

Search your system's documentation for `usleep` (microseconds) or `nanosleep` (nanoseconds).