# What does "select" do when nfds is 0?

Tags: c, linux

```
int select(int nfds, 
           fd_set *readfds, 
           fd_set *writefds, 
           fd_set *exceptfds, 
           struct timeval *timeout);
```

The first parameter of `select`, `nfds`, is supposed to be the maximum file descriptor plus 1, which should be at least 1.
But I have seen some codes set nfds to be 0, is this usage legal?
Plus, the return value of `select` is set to `EINVAL` when `nfds` is negative or `timeout` contains invalid value. Again, it does not specify what happened when `nfds` is 0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use select() instead of sleep()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125645/why-use-select-instead-of-sleep)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to use select as an alternative for `sleep`. I believe it is achieved by specyfying all parameters as 0/NULL except timeout. Consult

[Why use select() instead of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125645/why-use-select-instead-of-sleep)

Answer (score 5):

This [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) says that

> Some code calls select() with all three sets empty, nfds zero, and a non-NULL timeout as a fairly portable way to sleep with subsecond precision.

Comment: It should be noted, in case any newbies find this confusing, that `select` was the *only* portable way to do this before `nanosleep` was widely supported, and that quote has been in that man page for **that long**.

Answer (score 3):

It waits for the given timeout and then returns 0, or it returns sooner with `EINTR`.  If you think about it, this makes perfect sense and is in fact what the documentation says, even though it does not say it explicitly.  The same thing happens if all the sets are NULL or have no bits less than `nfds` set in them.