# Linux select system call precision of timeout

Tags: c++, linux, select, timeout, system-calls

When using `select` system call on linux to check if a socket is ready to be read and contains data, is there any difference when setting the timeout value to 0 (not nullptr but real zeros) and setting it to low amount of microseconds?

I am specially interested in the precision of the timeout. Let's say it can wait only 10ms on minimum, no matter what timeout I am giving, this would affect the polling frequency of this implementation a lot.

```
int socket= 5 ; //just for example, usually somewhere retreived
timeval timevalStruct;
timevalStruct.tv_sec=0;
timevalStruct.tv_usec=0; //Solution A
timevalStruct.tv_usec=1; //Solution B

fd_set in_set;

FD_ZERO(&in_set);
FD_SET(socket, &in_set);

select(socket + 1, &in_set, nullptr, nullptr, &timevalStruct); //how long does it wait here for minimum
```

Comment: The [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) is pretty clear on what happens, except that it doesn't specify what the "system clock granularity" is.

Comment: Why not test it ? There is lot of code where they prefer `select()` & `poll()` to put a monitor-thread to sleep. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125645/

Comment: There is `pselect()` which supports `nano seconds`; evidently they're accurate.

Comment: My 11 year old i3 2310M `select()` takes at most `2-5 μs` to return with `0 μs` wait; but takes `60-80 μs` even for `1μs` wait time. Same figures for `pselect()`. Current servers will be way faster.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, there is a lot of input there. I was aware of the "system clock granilarity" from the manpages and was looking for more details on that one. Was experiencing some weird things there, that it at least waited for 10ms instead of the given 1us. Not sure what to do with it so I am trying to ask you guys.

Comment: @SparKot how did you measure that? I can take time before and after the select, then print but it does not seem accurate to me, or at least the random spread is very high.