# What happens if a non-re-entrant linux function (say select) does not finish execution?

Tags: c, linux, reentrancy

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774986/linux-select-vs-ppoll-vs-pselect) and learned that 'select' is not reentrant. So what happens if a signal is delivered (for example SIGKILL) while we're in the middle of it. Does this mean we can never use it again?

I'm trying to solve [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091407/serial-port-becomes-unreadable-after-android-device-is-put-to-sleep) which I'm having with read and though maybe it's because of this.

Comment: SIGKILL is the Avada Kedavra of signals. If you get that signal, you're dead and your mom's love won't protect you.

Answer (score 4):

If a signal is delivered in the middle of a call to `select`, then the `select` will return `-1`, and set the `errno` to `EINTR`. That ends the call to `select`, and you're free to call `select` again.

What you *can't* do is call `select` inside of the signal handler. Because in that case you're calling `select` before the first `select` has returned. But of course, it makes no sense to call `select` in a signal handler, so you would never do that anyways.

Bottom line: if the signal is handled properly, there's no reason why you can't call `select` again after the signal.

Comment: What if the signal is SIGKILL? How can `select` handle SIGKILL?

Comment: @kptlronyttcna I admit that I ignored your choice of example for the signal, because if your program receives a SIGKILL, then it is terminated. In which case, the question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: the problem is that after SIGKILL I can no longer use `read` or `select`. Even if I close the program and open it again.

Comment: @kptlronyttcna Yes, I read the other question, but I don't have an answer for it. There's not enough code in that question for someone to reproduce the problem. So it's hard to know what went wrong.