# execute program for every 1min

Tags: c

I wanted to execute simple c program that call function every 1 minute.Please help me in coding.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("hello");
    fun1();
    printf("welcome");
    delay(1000);

}
void  fun1()
{
    printf("fun1 is called");

    delay(10000);
}

void delay(int k)
{

    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    {}
}
```

output i wanted in format:

```
hello
welcome
```

Each 10 time after 10 statement it should print fun1 is calledthen it should continue printing hello welcome anoter 10 times

Comment: how about using a cron job ?

Comment: If it on a windows system you could use task scheduler to run the program

Comment: OP needs to delay execution inside his program, not execute it every N seconds.

Comment: @AMPS what is the OS you are using, there are specific OS solutions to your problem.

Comment: i m using windows os. I need simple program in c where the function f1 should called every 1min .without affecting main program.i don't want use counter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [sleep](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sleeping.html) function. It will delay execution for a given amount of time. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3379146/147072) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/264363/147072) you have some more resources and examples.

Took the example from Mr. Anon in the first SO link I posted (specific to Windows):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf( "starting to sleep...\n" );
    Sleep( 3000 );   // sleep three seconds
    printf( "sleep ended\n" );
}
```

Indication is to watch out for the uppercase S.

Good luck!